# Applying Math.log To EditText

Tags: java, android, user-interface, math, android-edittext

I'm getting an error with my following code implementation.

***Math cannot be applied to android.widget.EditText***

Then, I googled for the issue and found a link [Math with an integer obtained from an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677747/math-with-an-integer-obtained-from-an-edittext). 
I tried to edit related codes. However, I'm yet to solve my issue.

This is my UI for respective class activity. Where you can see, that I will choose respective models from the spinner and the giving 4 different inputs.

[image]

Next is some parts of my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String tDistance = distanceEdit.getText().toString();
        String freqStr = freqEdit.getText().toString();
        String tBase = tHeightEdit.getText().toString();
        String rMobile = rHeightEdit.getText().toString();
        double distance = Double.parseDouble(!tDistance.isEmpty() ? tDistance : "0");
        double frequency = Double.parseDouble(!freqStr.isEmpty() ? freqStr : "0");
        //double frequency = Double.parseDouble(freqStr);
        double baseHeight = Double.parseDouble(!tBase.isEmpty() ? tBase : "0");
        double mobileHeight = Double.parseDouble(!rMobile.isEmpty() ? rMobile : "0");



        if(v == calButton) {
            //String freqStr = freqEdit.getText().toString();

            if(freqStr != null && !freqStr.isEmpty()) {
                mResult=69.55+26.16*Math.log(frequency)-13.82*Math.log(baseHeight)-antennaFac+(44.9-6.55*Math.log(baseHeight))*Math.log(distance);

            }
        } else
        if(v == clearButton) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg2) {
            case 0:
                antennaFac = (1.1*Math.log(freqEdit)-0.7)*rHeightEdit-(1.56*Math.log(freqEdit)-0.8);//Error from freqEdit - Math cannot be applied to android.widget.EditText
//Error when trying to use frequency variable - Unable to resolve symbol
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

My problem is currently in the onItemSelected method where my freqEdit parameter shows the error I highlighted above. To my own understanding, it was supposed to be frequency variable which has already been declared in the OnClick method. However, it says that "cannot resolve symbol 'frequency'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your `frequency`variable inside your `onClick`function, and the `onItemSelected`is in a completely different scope.

Declare ´frequency´ as a member class and update its value in `onClick` as you are already doing, then you will be able to use it in your `onItemSelected` method.

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

You can also recalculate your `frequency` value in your `onClick` method executing the following statements again.

```
String freqStr = freqEdit.getText().toString();
double frequency = Double.parseDouble(!freqStr.isEmpty() ? freqStr : "0");
```

Comment: Did you mean by putting it both the method? And regarding your earlier comment on declaring the frequency as a member class. I tried OnClick value = new OnClick; value.frequency but it states cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: You should put `double frequency`as a class member (just after `class xxx extends ...`)  Then in your `onClick` method write the following `frequency = Double.parseDouble(!freqStr.isEmpty() ? freqStr : "0");` so in this way you will be updating your class member. Finally your symbol will be available in your `onItemSelected` method

Comment: If it helped you, you should mark any answer as correct, if not keep asking :)

Answer (score 0):

**What you are doing:**

In the `case 0:`
You are trying to do a **math** operation on **View element** which is not a valid action.

**Possible Solution:**

Rather than `freqEdit` you have to use `freqStr` *(which is nothing but the value of that edit text)*

**NOTE:** Make sure you are converting the **string to double**
For converting string to double follow this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867296/1276495).

Comment: I tried both frequency & freqStr. It either states that I have to declare local variable

Comment: Rather than declaring local variable, make those variable global. It will enable you to access those variable from the onItemSelected